# How can I align my navbar buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navigation bar currently looks like this:

[image: bad navigation bar]

My code is below:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Text Planner
      </a>
    </div>


    <% if user_signed_in? %>


      <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">Welcome, <strong><%= current_user.first_name.to_s+" "+current_user.last_name.to_s %></strong></p>

        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <%= link_to "Home", home_path, :class => 'btn btn-default navbar-button' %>
          <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle navbar-button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</div>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Search For Events", root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "My Bookmarks", user_bookmarks_path(current_user.id)%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "My Upcoming Reminders", user_reminders_path(current_user.id)%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "My Profile", user_path(current_user.id)%></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
              </ul>
        </div>



    <% else %>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path, :class => 'navbar-text' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-text'  %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-text'  %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</nav>
```

How do I move the home and menu buttons to the left and center them vertically? Also, I would like to keep them clickable buttons while removing the outline of a button with the white background so they match the left side of my navigation bar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post your output (HTML) in a minimal, working example. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, actually, set your line-height and div height to the same (here's a quick example):

```
#navbar a{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

This is provided your buttons are formed using CSS, but I believe it works for other elements, as well.